# Why are this operands returning False?

Tags: python, boolean, operators

I have a counter-intuitive issue while writing my script in Python.

```
>>> def foo():
...     return False
... 
>>> foo()
False
>>> foo()==False
True
>>> i=1
>>> i!=0
True
>>> foo()==False & i!=0
False
>>> (foo()==False) & i!=0
True
>>>
```

As you can see **foo()==False** returns **True** as **i!=0** does, so intuitively I would expect **True & True** to return **True**, however when I run **foo()==False & i!=0** I receive False and when I run **(foo()==False) & i!=0** I get True as was initially expected. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple pythons order of operations. In

```
foo()==False & i!=0
```

the bitwise and `&` has a higher precedence than the `==`. Thus, you're really evaluating

```
foo()==(False & i)!=0
```

If you replace your bitwise and `&` with a logical and `and`, your answer comes out as expected

```
>>> foo()==False and i!=0
True
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=459269&seqNum=11)

Answer (score 1):

`&` has higher precedence than `==` and `!=` in python so use `(foo()==False) & (i!=0)` to make sure that no operand precedence conflict occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that there is operator precedence in python, refer to the [doc:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comparisons(`==,!=`) has lower precedence than Bitwise AND(`&`):

`foo()==False & i!=0` ==> `foo()==(False & i)!=0`

`(foo()==False) & i!=0`  ==> `((foo()==False) & i)!=0`

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the Bitwise operator, you can use it to see if a number is even or odd. Since `foo()` returns `False` which is considered 0 and 0 is not considered an odd number, theBitwise operator `&` will return `False` because is not an odd number.

Answer (score 0):

As per python documentation 6.16. Operator precedence & has higher precedence than == or !=
therefore when you run foo()==False & i!=0 is evaluated as follows

```
foo()==False & i!=0
foo() == (False & True)!= 0  #since 1 is nothing but True
Foo() == False != False
```

which is false.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#summary

I initially tried to include a table but dont know how to do that in stackoverflow. sorry.